Mongodb Dockerfile which automatically seeds data
I would like to create a single Dockerfile for MongoDB which will start mongod and seed the database with .json files (if they were mounted).
Here is what it currently looks like:
FROM mongo:7.0.6

COPY ./tools/db /import

RUN echo -e "mongod; for f in /import/*.json; do name=\$(basename \$f | cut -d'.' -f1); mongoimport --db=APPDB --collection=\$name --jsonArray --file=\$f; done;" > /usr/local/bin/run.sh
RUN chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/run.sh

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/run.sh"]

When I run this container, everything after mongod command does not run. However, if I login to the container, I can run the shell script and the import works fine. I think I understand why this does not work, because the "mongod" takes over the terminal and does not give control back, therefore the data seeding does not execute. I tried adding the "--fork" flag to mongod, but it seems like mongod does not even start with that.
Is there anyway to get this to work?

The Mongo DB is normally started via the image entrypoint. There is a specific folder, /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/, on the image which is intended for startup scripts. I'd suggest the following:

Create a file run.sh in the same folder as your Dockerfile.

#!/bin/bash

for f in /import/*.json
do
    name=$(basename $f | cut -d'.' -f1)
    mongoimport --db=APPDB --collection=$name --jsonArray --file=$f
done


Copy run.sh into /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/.

FROM mongo:7.0.6

COPY ./tools/db /import
COPY run.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

If you now build and run your image you should find that the JSON seed files are imported when the database starts.
